# How do I get the TLS 1.2 KB4019276 patch to work on windows server 2008?

Tags: ssl

I checked for duplicate posts on here but none of them seem to solve my issue. If anyone finds one I didn't, please post it.

Windows Server 2008 Standard
Version 6.0 (Build 6003: Service Pack 2)

**Firefox:**
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to sparkleflooring.com.au. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

**Chrome:**
This site can’t provide a secure connection sparkleflooring.com.au sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**Background:** I have been working on installing a certificate on my local website http://sparkleflooring.com.au and found out the hard way that the certificate clients don't work on server 2008 for x86 anymore. Finally got the certificate installed by using a ubuntu host and copying it across using https://rajbos.github.io/blog/2019/08/27/LetsEncrypt-Windows.

Now im getting these ssl errors which lead me to the information that TLS is required but not installed on 2008 server. I tried the suggested patch https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb4019276 but it said it's not suitable for my system. I then used a 3rd party stand alone program to add the keys but still it doesn't work.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: this isn't directly programming related - [sf] would be a better place to ask

Comment: @DanielA.White Ok thanks. I'll repost there.